# Clojure Zipper over a heterogeneous tree

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, zipper

I'm having problems writing a zipper that can traverse a heterogeneous tree of nodes. I have i) a list of maps. Each map has ii) an :inputs key, whose value is a list of maps.

I want to use a zipper to visit each of those leaves and add a computed value. The code block and input tree data are below. I can't seem to get the zipper code to visit the leaf nodes, and add { :thing 123 }. I must be missing something simple. Any insights?

A)

```
      (loop [loc (zip/zipper  (or map? list?)
                              #((if (map? %1)              ;; get children of a node
                                  (:inputs %1)
                                  %1 ))
                              #(%1)                            ;; create a new node 
                              (:input-layer neural-network)) ] 

        (if (zip/end? loc) 
          (zip/root loc) 
          (if (map? loc) 
            (recur  (zip/next 
                      (zip/edit loc merge { :thing 123 } ))) 
            (recur (zip/next loc)) 
          ) 
        ) 
      )
```

B)

```
     ({:inputs
       ({:key :avolume, :value 2.25, :weight 0.4283380545172636, :bias 0}
        {:key :bvolume, :value 3.0, :weight 0.6970037374879661, :bias 0}
        {:key :ask, :value 1.32379, :weight 0.5387437158323669, :bias 0}
        {:key :bid, :value 1.3239, :weight 0.4648184032361037, :bias 0}
        {:key :time, :value 1.335902400676, :weight 0.43632873607404554, :bias 0}),
       :id "583c10bfdbd326ba34aed329139df6be2487ffc"}
      {:inputs
       ({:key :avolume, :value 2.25, :weight 0.13162215440222336, :bias 0}
        {:key :bvolume, :value 3.0, :weight 0.23886901184352727, :bias 0}
        {:key :ask, :value 1.32379, :weight 0.8408470512339872, :bias 0}
        {:key :bid, :value 1.3239, :weight 0.27071013797961796, :bias 0}
        {:key :time, :value 1.335902400676, :weight 0.6304505838898373, :bias 0}),
       :id "583c10bfdbd326ba34aed329139df6be2487ffd"}
      {:inputs
       ({:key :avolume, :value 2.25, :weight 0.8236972641966921, :bias 0}
        {:key :bvolume, :value 3.0, :weight 0.32421537754016705, :bias 0}
        {:key :ask, :value 1.32379, :weight 0.966306328543246, :bias 0}
        {:key :bid, :value 1.3239, :weight 0.8891668220470931, :bias 0}
        {:key :time, :value 1.335902400676, :weight 0.278993745549462, :bias 0}),
       :id "583c10bfdbd326ba34aed329139df6be2487ffe"}
      {:inputs
       ({:key :avolume, :value 2.25, :weight 0.27388486254027167, :bias 0}
        {:key :bvolume, :value 3.0, :weight 0.33659579299487363, :bias 0}
        {:key :ask, :value 1.32379, :weight 0.16610378593177033, :bias 0}
        {:key :bid, :value 1.3239, :weight 0.6964784902474896, :bias 0}
        {:key :time, :value 1.335902400676, :weight 0.6306732906337643, :bias 0}),
       :id "583c10bfdbd326ba34aed329139df6be2487fff"}
      {:inputs
       ({:key :avolume, :value 2.25, :weight 0.8819171698935051, :bias 0}
        {:key :bvolume, :value 3.0, :weight 0.5944805362120958, :bias 0}
        {:key :ask, :value 1.32379, :weight 0.9060962647355373, :bias 0}
        {:key :bid, :value 1.3239, :weight 0.37647418075176464, :bias 0}
        {:key :time, :value 1.335902400676, :weight 0.7797681719480866, :bias 0}),
       :id "583c10bfdbd326ba34aed329139df6be2488000"})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think part of zipper that creates new nodes is incorrect. If you read [definition of zipper function](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.zip-api.html#clojure.zip/zipper), you'll see that `make-node` is called with 2 arguments: current node, sequence of new children. Function should return new node.

Expression that you use `#(%1)` shouldn't work at all, as you're trying to call map or list as a function.

Also expression `(or map? list?)` doesn't really do what you want.

---

I adapted it for vectors just for the test.

```
(defn mk-zip [root]
  (let [branch? (fn [node]
                  (when node
                    (or (and (map? node) (contains? node :inputs))
                        (vector? node))))
        children (fn [node]
                   (cond 
                     (nil? node) nil
                     (map? node) (:inputs node)
                     :else node))
        make-node (fn [node children]
                    (cond
                      (nil? node) nil
                      (map? node) (assoc node :inputs children)
                      (vector? node) (into [] children)
                      :else node))]
    (zip/zipper branch? children make-node root)))

(def root [{:inputs
            [{:key :avolume, :value 2.25, :weight 0.4283380545172636, :bias 0}
             {:key :bvolume, :value 3.0, :weight 0.6970037374879661, :bias 0}
             {:key :ask, :value 1.32379, :weight 0.5387437158323669, :bias 0}
             {:key :bid, :value 1.3239, :weight 0.4648184032361037, :bias 0}
             {:key :time, :value 1.335902400676, :weight 0.43632873607404554, :bias 0}],
            :id "583c10bfdbd326ba34aed329139df6be2487ffc"}])
```

Updating map items now works:

```
(def z (mk-zip root))
(-> z zip/next zip/down 
    (zip/insert-right {:key :new :value -10}) 
    zip/up
    zip/node)
```

Prints:

```
{:inputs
 ({:key :avolume, :weight 0.4283380545172636, :bias 0, :value 2.25}
  {:key :new, :value -10}
  {:key :bvolume, :weight 0.6970037374879661, :bias 0, :value 3.0}
  {:key :ask, :weight 0.5387437158323669, :bias 0, :value 1.32379}
  {:key :bid, :weight 0.4648184032361037, :bias 0, :value 1.3239}
  {:key :time,
   :weight 0.43632873607404554,
   :bias 0,
   :value 1.335902400676}),
 :id "583c10bfdbd326ba34aed329139df6be2487ffc"}
```

Comment: Cool. It turned out to be that, and my confusion over a zipper's **location** with it's **node** when traversing the tree. Thanks friend.